# Use of *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, args, keyword-argument

So I have difficulty with the concept of `*args` and `**kwargs`.

So far I have learned that:

- `*args` = list of arguments - as positional arguments
- `**kwargs` = dictionary - whose keys become separate keyword arguments and the values become values of these arguments.

I don't understand what programming task this would be helpful for.

Maybe:

I think to enter lists and dictionaries as arguments of a function AND at the same time as a wildcard, so I can pass ANY argument?

Is there a simple example to explain how `*args` and `**kwargs` are used?

Also the tutorial I found used just the "*" and a variable name.

Are `*args` and `**kwargs` just placeholders or do you use exactly `*args` and `**kwargs` in the code?

Comment: Once you get a grasp on these, you'll never want to miss them (especially, if you ever had to deal with PHP's `func_*_args()`).

Comment: The docs are at http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#id13, btw.

Comment: Actually, these 2 argument formats can be added to any function declaration as long as they are the last 2. Note the order: `explicit args, then *args, then **kwargs`. e.g. `def foo (arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs): ...`

Comment: (If you are in Javascript there's `arguments` array that's similar)

Comment: In some other languages the `*args` form would be known as variadic arguments.

Answer (score 1785, accepted):

[The syntax is the `*` and `**`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).  The names `*args` and `**kwargs` are only by convention but there's no hard requirement to use them.

You would use `*args` when you're not sure how many arguments might be passed to your function, i.e. it allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function.  For example:

```
>>> def print_everything(*args):
        for count, thing in enumerate(args):
...         print( '{0}. {1}'.format(count, thing))
...
>>> print_everything('apple', 'banana', 'cabbage')
0. apple
1. banana
2. cabbage
```

Similarly, `**kwargs` allows you to handle named arguments that you have not defined in advance:

```
>>> def table_things(**kwargs):
...     for name, value in kwargs.items():
...         print( '{0} = {1}'.format(name, value))
...
>>> table_things(apple = 'fruit', cabbage = 'vegetable')
cabbage = vegetable
apple = fruit
```

You can use these along with named arguments too.  The explicit arguments get values first and then everything else is passed to `*args` and `**kwargs`.  The named arguments come first in the list.  For example:

```
def table_things(titlestring, **kwargs)
```

You can also use both in the same function definition but `*args` must occur before `**kwargs`.

You can also use the `*` and `**` syntax when calling a function.  For example:

```
>>> def print_three_things(a, b, c):
...     print( 'a = {0}, b = {1}, c = {2}'.format(a,b,c))
...
>>> mylist = ['aardvark', 'baboon', 'cat']
>>> print_three_things(*mylist)
a = aardvark, b = baboon, c = cat
```

As you can see in this case it takes the list (or tuple) of items and unpacks it. By this it matches them to the arguments in the function.  Of course, you could have a `*` both in the function definition and in the function call.

Comment: how would you look this up in the python help/documentation?

Comment: @Alex: [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists)

Comment: It appears impossible to expand a list passed as a positional argument in the middle of a function call as in `function_call(arg1,arg2,*expanded_list_args,arg4,arg5)`. The expanded list may only be followed by keyword arguments I believe. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: @mlh3789 yes, and this works with python3, only.
But what is really a bit weird: this kinda works on assignments:
`a, b, *c, d, e = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`
assigns c to [3, 4]. A bit confusing

Comment: In the example above, `mylist` is like `an array` in JS. Our normal method of `print_three_things` takes 3 args. Passing it to print_three_things(`*mylist`), the `*` annotation is more or less like the `spreading operator` in ES6. Let me know if my consideration is okay or wrong? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for pointing out you can send tuples/lists in *args.. super helpful

Comment: `You can also use both in the same function definition but *args must occur before **kwargs.` Why?

Comment: Is there any performance difference b/w both of them?

Comment: There is no example of using two asterisks when calling a function. It would look similar to whats there at the bottom but instead of mylist it would take mydict with names for each entry and use the doubled asterisks when calling the method.

Answer (score 513):

One place where the use of `*args` and `**kwargs` is quite useful is for subclassing.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value1, value2):
        # do something with the values
        print value1, value2

class MyFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something else, don't care about the args
        print 'myfoo'
        super(MyFoo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

This way you can extend the behaviour of the Foo class, without having to know too much about Foo. This can be quite convenient if you are programming to an API which might change. MyFoo just passes all arguments to the Foo class.

Comment: This answer really only makes sense if you already understand * and **.

Comment: I don't get it. If your API changes, you still have to change all the places you instantiate the child classes. And if you're changing all those places, then you might as well have the signature of the child class be fixed, instead of hacked together with args and kwargs for no reason.

Your reasoning about this not requiring knowledge of Foo is meaningless, because as soon as the set signature of the Foo constructor changes, all your MyFoo instantiation calls will have to change as well. This requires knowledge of Foo and the parameters its constructor requires.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic An example where this could be used is in a situation where you are providing an add-on for an existing product and want to override/extend some functionality. By using *args and **kwargs this add-on will keep functioning if the underlying product changes. However, instantiating MyFoo happens outside the add-on. Does that make (more) sense? (Having said this: a decorator is a better example of when you can use *args and **kwargs.)

Comment: how do you extend this for specific arguments of the subclass?

Comment: @HananShteingart For example like this: def __init__(self, foo, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: For this particular example, there's no guarantee that `value1` and `value2` will get passed. Also, if more than 2 arguments are passed, an exception is raised. To conclude, this is not a good example of argument forwarding.

Comment: ... and then one can create objects like `f = MyFoo((1,2,3),{'third':4,'fifth':5})` . Here, first tuple (1,2,3) will go as argument to 'args' and dictionary later will go to 'kwargs'. It is important to note that a call like `f = MyFoo(1,2,3,4,5)` becomes wrong as Python interpreter cannt figure out which argument should be part of tuple and which should belong to kwargs (dictionary). So when using `*args` and `**kwargs` together you pretty much have to first form the arguments to be passed. If there was no `**kwargs` there , second call would have been perfectly fine.

Comment: This is a very limited use case and most people will not use this pattern in the scenario you've described. They'll use it as a hack - I've seen it and it can cause a lot of grief. You are essentially even bypassing the limited checks that the Python interpreter provides.

Comment: @kavinyao: you clearly **do not know** Python and **do not tested** what you wrote. `value2` goes as first element in `args`, so no exception.

Comment: @VIFI: the same to you... The dict will go as the second element of `args`. To have them as kwargs, you have to write `MyFoo(1, 2, 3, third=4, fifth=5)`. And `MyFoo(1,2,3,4,5)` will create an `args=(1,2,3,4,5)` Please, you both, read the docs and test before saying **completely wrong** affirmations.

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic: see this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34393976/1763602 As you can see, I don't need to know the firm of `dict` constructor to create my own map. If the `dict` API changes, my `MultiDict` will continue to work. Of course you have to change your code, but also who used `dict` have to change it. But the code of `MultiDict` will need no change.

Comment: How would you tackle this in C++?

Answer (score 341):

Here's an example that uses 3 different types of parameters.

```
def func(required_arg, *args, **kwargs):
    # required_arg is a positional-only parameter.
    print required_arg

    # args is a tuple of positional arguments,
    # because the parameter name has * prepended.
    if args: # If args is not empty.
        print args

    # kwargs is a dictionary of keyword arguments,
    # because the parameter name has ** prepended.
    if kwargs: # If kwargs is not empty.
        print kwargs

>>> func()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

>>> func("required argument")
required argument

>>> func("required argument", 1, 2, '3')
required argument
(1, 2, '3')

>>> func("required argument", 1, 2, '3', keyword1=4, keyword2="foo")
required argument
(1, 2, '3')
{'keyword2': 'foo', 'keyword1': 4}
```

Answer (score 76):

Here's one of my favorite places to use the `**` syntax as in Dave Webb's final example:

```
mynum = 1000
mystr = 'Hello World!'
print("{mystr} New-style formatting is {mynum}x more fun!".format(**locals()))
```

I'm not sure if it's terribly fast when compared to just using the names themselves, but it's a lot easier to type!

Comment: hey, this guy invented Python 3.6 f-strings before it was cool

Comment: @cat please explain? what are you referring to exactly? didn't the `format` method already exist even in Python 2?

Comment: @dabadaba f-strings, not format strings (e.g. `f'{mystr} New-style formatting is {mynum}x more fun!'`)

Comment: @dabadaba congrats on being one of todays [lucky 10k](https://xkcd.com/1053/)

Comment: @dabadaba see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498

Comment: Please make sure you really don't use any string from user, otherwise this will surely create a big security hole.

Comment: @hegez in what contexts? If you're using string formatting for SQL queries then you're either stupid or you haven't learned about parameterized queries yet.

Comment: @WayneWerner nobody was talking about SQL queries (though I understand they play a big role of example in this field). I think I thought about allowing the user to even partially set the string which will be formatted. Very simplified case: `string = '{locale_username}: ' + input(); string.format(**locals())`. Also, programmers should only `.format()` the string only once.

Answer (score 49):

One case where *args and **kwargs are useful is when writing wrapper functions (such as decorators) that need to be able accept arbitrary arguments to pass through to the function being wrapped.  For example, a simple decorator that prints the arguments and return value of the function being wrapped:

```
def mydecorator( f ):
   @functools.wraps( f )
   def wrapper( *args, **kwargs ):
      print "Calling f", args, kwargs
      v = f( *args, **kwargs )
      print "f returned", v
      return v
   return wrapper
```

Answer (score 44):

*args and **kwargs are special-magic features of Python.
Think of a function that could have an unknown number of arguments. For example, for whatever reasons, you want to have function that sums an unknown number of numbers (and you don't want to use the built-in sum function). So you write this function:

```
def sumFunction(*args):
  result = 0
  for x in args:
    result += x
  return result
```

and use it like: sumFunction(3,4,6,3,6,8,9).

**kwargs has a diffrent function. With **kwargs you can give arbitrary keyword arguments to a function and you can access them as a dictonary.

```
def someFunction(**kwargs):
  if 'text' in kwargs:
    print kwargs['text']
```

Calling someFunction(text="foo") will print foo.

Comment: Finally, a simple-enough use case that can help me understand `*args` and `**kwargs` XD. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 20):

Just imagine you have a function but you don't want to restrict the number of parameter it takes.
Example:

```
>>> import operator
>>> def multiply(*args):
...  return reduce(operator.mul, args)
```

Then you use this function like:

```
>>> multiply(1,2,3)
6

or

>>> numbers = [1,2,3]
>>> multiply(*numbers)
6
```

Answer (score 18):

The names `*args` and `**kwargs` or `**kw` are purely by convention. It makes it easier for us to read each other's code

One place it is handy is when using the struct module

`struct.unpack()` returns a tuple whereas `struct.pack()` uses a variable number of arguments. When manipulating data it is convenient to be able to pass a tuple to `struck.pack()` eg.

```py
tuple_of_data = struct.unpack(format_str, data)
# ... manipulate the data
new_data = struct.pack(format_str, *tuple_of_data)
```

without this ability you would be forced to write

```py
new_data = struct.pack(format_str, tuple_of_data[0], tuple_of_data[1], tuple_of_data[2],...)
```

which also means the if the format_str changes and the size of the tuple changes, I'll have to go back and edit that really long line

Answer (score 10):

Note that *args/**kwargs is part of function-calling syntax, and not really an operator. This has a particular side effect that I ran into, which is that you can't use *args expansion with the print statement, since print is not a function.

This seems reasonable:

```
def myprint(*args):
    print *args
```

Unfortunately it doesn't compile (syntax error).

This compiles:

```
def myprint(*args):
    print args
```

But prints the arguments as a tuple, which isn't what we want.

This is the solution I settled on:

```
def myprint(*args):
    for arg in args:
        print arg,
    print
```

Comment: Of course there's always `from __future__ import print_function` :)

Comment: print is a function in Python3:) http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Answer (score 8):

These parameters are typically used for proxy functions, so the proxy can pass any input parameter to the target function.

```
def foo(bar=2, baz=5):
    print bar, baz

def proxy(x, *args, **kwargs): # reqire parameter x and accept any number of additional arguments
    print x
    foo(*args, **kwargs) # applies the "non-x" parameter to foo

proxy(23, 5, baz='foo') # calls foo with bar=5 and baz=foo
proxy(6)# calls foo with its default arguments
proxy(7, bar='asdas') # calls foo with bar='asdas' and leave baz default argument
```

But since these parameters hide the actual parameter names, it is better to avoid them.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at python docs (docs.python.org in the FAQ), but more specifically for a good explanation [the mysterious miss args and mister kwargs (courtesy of archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017032628/http://pypatterns.net/post/2009/10/the-mysterious-miss-args-and-mister-kwargs) (the original, dead link is [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20101017032628/http://pypatterns.net/post/2009/10/the-mysterious-miss-args-and-mister-kwargs)).

In a nutshell, both are used when optional parameters to a function or method are used. 
As Dave says, *args is used when you don't know how many arguments may be passed, and **kwargs when you want to handle parameters specified by name and value as in:

```
myfunction(myarg=1)
```

Comment: Another nice tutorial: http://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/

Comment: _'Here is a link, and also what that other person said'_ is not a useful answer. About the only thing this answer actually says on its own is to imply that `**kwargs` is required to use named arguments, which is false. It's only needed to handle _arbitrary_ named arguments.