# Python 2.7 - writing string on a new line

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

py 2.7
I want to append a new line to my string when I call a.write()
the problem is that the contenent is a variable.
so, when i write

```
a.write(x,"/n")
```

it gives me error cause i can't put more than 1 argument in ().
any suggest?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-everytime

Comment: thanks. i'm new. still learning.
and very thank you for the fast answer :)

Comment: @HANZO you are welcome. All the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways of doing it

- `a.write(x+"\n")`
- `a.write('{}\n'.format(x)`
- `a.write('%s\n'%(x))`

*Note* - `\n` is newline and not `/n`