# How do i write a new line or \n into a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a simple code where i wanted to write 2 files into 1. I wanted to write a new line or '\n' after the first file is written. I tried using files.write but unable to do it. Can someone help me in this?

This is my code:

```
files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
files1 = run('ls -ltr /opt/web')
with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write(files)
with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "a") as fi:
    fi.write(files1)
```

Here, after the files is written, i wanted to add a new line before files1 is appended to the same file.

Comment: What do you mean by "section" in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing string to a file on a new line everytime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-everytime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write [**os.linesep**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep)  into your file before writing into it from `files1` as in code snippet below:

```
import os

with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "a") as fi:
    fi.write(os.linesep)
    fi.write(files1)
    # Or simply fi.write(os.linesep + files1)
```

Also didn't catch idea of two separate `with` statements, why not to write all data within one `with`:

```
import os

files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
files1 = run('ls -ltr /opt/web')
with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "w") as fo:
    fo.write(files)
    fo.write(os.linesep)
    fo.write(files1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I didnt know about this single usage of with statement.

Answer (score 2):

3 similar approaches:

1 - Concatenate 2 lists and write once

```
files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
files1 = run('ls -ltr /opt/web')
to_write = files + files1
with open(section + "_tmp" + ".txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(to_write)
```

2 - Write a new line before writing the second list

```
files = run('ls -ltr /opt/nds')
files1 = run('ls -ltr /opt/web')
with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(files)
    f.write("\n")
    f.write(files1)
```

3 - List all files at once rather than doing them twice

```
files = run('ls -ltr /opt/(nds|web)')
with open(section + "_tmp"+".txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(files)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you try something like this to add a line.

```
>>> f = open('C:\Code\myfile.txt','w')
>>> f.write('''
... my name
... is
... xyz
... ''')
18
>>> f.close()
```

The contents will be " my name
                       is
                       xyz "

Here begin with f.write(''' or f.write(""" and end with ''') or """)

Ex:-

```
f.write('''

             ''')
```

adds a line