# Python: how to write a list of lists to a text file so sub items appear in new lines?

Tags: python, csv

I am new to programming and Python and need to write a script so I can output data to Excel. For this purpose I am currently writing to a CSV.

However, I have a requirement to show this data so it is readable and am not sure how to achieve this.

I have a matrix of data

```
[
 ['FileName', 'File1', 'File2'], 
 ['Count', '1643', '1646'], 
 ['SomeNumbers', ['-15,51,-58,17'], ['-15,51,-58,17']],  
 ['MoreData', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
]
```

To print this, I wrote:

```
for item in matrix:
    writer.writerow(item)
```

I wrote the results to a CSV and got this:

```
FileName    FileA   FileB
FeatureType Polygon Polygon
FeatureCount    1643    1646
SomeNumbers ['-15,51,-58,17'], ['-15,51,-58,17']
MoreData    ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

What I would like to do is to write code such that I get output like this instead:

```
FileName    FileA   FileB
FeatureType Polygon Polygon
FeatureCount    1643    1646
SomeNumbers     -15     -15
                 51      51
                -58    -58
                 17     17
MoreData    a       a
            b       b
            c       c
            d       d
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing string to a file on a new line everytime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-everytime)

Comment: Can you supply the entire code necessary to reproduce the problem, please?  Also, please clarify whether you're writing this data to a CSV file, printing it to the console, or both.