# How to format the file output Python 3

Tags: python

I have made a code which asks the users name and age. It asks age and stores it using :

```
name = input("")
```

And the name uses the same.
I have outputted the age to file like so:

```
f = open('UserDetails')
f.write (name)
f.write (age)
f.close ()
```

I would like to be able to format this as in the file it just appears like:

```
James42Brian20Charlie56
```

I would like to make it be like :

```
James 42
Brian 20
Charlie 56
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Ok, let's do that: your question is lacking the code you have written, so we can apply the needed changes on it. You could also format the desired output as code, to make it more visible.

Comment: Literally my code is tiny. It asks the user to enter name and age, then it outputs to file. I did add the code to my question as text as I cannot figure out how to add it as code ( some features are not supported on ios)

Comment: @Gordon Adding as code is indenting by 4 spaces on a new line. you can also use backticks (shared with the tilde symbol on a qwerty keyboard) to do inline `code`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [writing string to a file on a new line everytime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-everytime)

Comment: I deleted the comments about being downvoted, but if you would like to stop that, then your can read the various topics of [asking help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
f = open('UserDetails','a')
name = input("Name? ")
f.write ("{} ".format(name))
age = input("Age? ")
f.write ("{}\n".format(age))
f.close ()
```

I would do something like this
You can put a while loop where needed
OR
You can run it multiple times if you wish to add another person

Answer (score 2):

Use [`string.format`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#format) with a newline character like so:

```
f = open('UserDetails', 'a')
f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(name, age))
f.close()
```

Comment: It is now saying that the f in f.close has incorrect syntax??

Comment: You should probably be opening the file with the `'a'` flag so you can append your newly-written lines, or possibly with the `'w'` flag if you want to overwrite previously-written ones.

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting, and what's the exact code you're using? You likely have a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but did you try something like this?

```
separator = ' '
f = open('UserDetails') 
f.write (name + separator) 
f.write (str(age) + separator) 
f.close ()
```

It might not show exactly how you want it, but the idea is to use string concatenation and see if that works (including the new line symbol '\n'').

That said, without seeing the actual code you've written, it's hard to say much else.

Comment: You're correct. Using string.format would be the best option here, as shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = input("")
age = input("")
f = open('UserDetails','a')
f.write ("{0} {1}\n".format(name, age))
f.close()
```

Comment: This is python 2 syntax; the OP specified python 3

Comment: I tried this, and it has started claiming that the f in f.close has an invalid syntax ??

Comment: just remove the space after the word close.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The `with open as` syntax is preferred over needing to manually close a file, and this will loop until you kill the script.

```
with open("UserDetails", "a") as f:
    while True:
        name = input("name: ")
        age = int(input("age: "))
        f.write("{0} {1}\n".format(name, age))
```