# How to write variables to a new line in a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
f = open("text.txt", "w+")
var2 = input()
f.write(var2'\n')
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing string to a file on a new line every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-every-time)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before asking beginner-level questions, you should search for existing solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
f = open("text.txt", "w+")
var2 = input()
f.write(var2 + '\n')
f.close()
```

But, this is a better way to do it

```
with open("text.txt", "w+") as f:
    f.write(var2 + '\n')
```

Comment: This is a good answer but you should recommend using with to open files

Answer (score -1):

if `var` is a string, you can just do `f.write(var + '\n')`. If `var` is not a string, you will need to do `f.write(str(var) + '\n')`

Comment: var will always be a string, it comes from input