# Can't delete item form shopping cart

Tags: python

My code works with adding and deleting one item only. However, when I add multiple items, I'm unable to delete any of them. I think the issue is that my code reads entire string (all of items including spaces) as one single item. How do I separate them in the cart?

```
file = open('/Users/home/Shopping list.txt', 'w')
file.write("Shopping list\n")
file.close()

print("Welcome to the shopping list creator")
print()

def shoppinglist():
print('''Choose 1 to veiw your shopping list.
Choose 2 to add an item to your shopping list.
Choose 3 to delete an item from your shopping list.
Choose 4 to exit the program.''')
print()
choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))

if choice == 1:
    shoppinglist_file = open('/Users/home/Shopping list.txt')
    print()
    print(shoppinglist_file.read())
    print()
    shoppinglist_file.close()
    shoppinglist()

elif choice == 2:
    shoppinglist_file = open('/Users/home/Shopping list.txt', 'a')
    print()
    thing_to_add = str(input("What would you like to add to your shopping list? "))
    shoppinglist_file.write("%s" % (thing_to_add))
    shoppinglist_file.close()
    print()
    shoppinglist()

elif choice == 3:
    shoppinglist_file = open('/Users/home/Shopping list.txt')
    shoppinglistfile_list = shoppinglist_file.readlines()
    print()
    print(shoppinglistfile_list)
    del_item = str(input())
    print(del_item)
    shoppinglistfile_list.remove(del_item)
    shoppinglist_file.close()
    shoppinglist_file = open('/Users/home/Shopping list.txt', 'w')

    shoppinglist_file.write(str(shoppinglistfile_list))
    shoppinglist_file.close()
    print()
    shoppinglist()

elif choice == 4:
    print()
    print("Thank you for using ths program")
    print("--------")

else:
    print()
    print("Please enter a valid option")
    print()
    shoppinglist()


shoppinglist()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing string to a file on a new line every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-every-time)

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing a line break to signal the end of a line.

Try adding `\n` like this:

```
shoppinglist_file.write("%s\n" % (thing_to_add))
```

Comment: When I try this approach, I'm unable to delete an entry form the shopping cart is it cannot be found:
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Answer (score 0):

First of all, like MGP mentioned, you are not adding a line break. You first need to fix that to

```py
shoppinglist_file.write("%s\n" % (thing_to_add))
```

Now as you can see when `print(shoppinglistfile_list)` is run, `readlines()` method does not trim any new line characters. So for example, if your `Shopping List.txt` looks like:

```py
apples\n
oranges\n
bananas\n
```

(new line character written explicitly for explanation)

then your `shoppinglistfile_list` would be `['apples\n', 'oranges\n', 'bananas\n']`.

`input()` however treats the new line character as a delimiter, which means you cannot possibly pass `\n` using it. For the same example, therefore, typing in `apples` will not remove `apples\n`. This is easy to fix: simply add `\n`.

```py
shoppinglistfile_list.remove(del_item + '\n')
```

You also might want to change how the shopping list is printed, as `['apples\n', 'oranges\n', 'bananas\n']` isn't the prettiest (to me at least).