# How to keep the formatation of a list?

Tags: python, list, csv

So I have several Lists of integers in a csv file like this:

```
["12345","325462"]

["214356","53645"]

...
```

I have to calculate the digit sum of every integer from the lists. After doing that I have to print the results like this:

```
"digit_sum1", "digit_sum2"

"digit_sum3", "digit_sum4"

...
```

The lists are in a .csv file.
How can I keep the original formatation from the original list? Or how can I make the results print like that? The results also have to be in another .csv file.

This is my actual function:

```
def convert_raw_data(source, destination):

    with open(source) as fr, open(destination, "x") as fw:
        for line in fr:
            splitted_lines_0 = line.splitlines()
            for elem in splitted_lines_0:
                splitted_lines = elem.split(",")
                for numbers in splitted_lines:
                    sums = calculate_digit_sum(numbers)
                    fr.write(str(sums))
```

and the output of "sums" looks like this:

```
int1

int2

int3

...
```

And when printed in the csv file its all a long string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please include your current attempt?

Comment: Could you include a line or two of your input file and what you want the output for that input to look like?

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53751821/edit) it.

Comment: Seems like you need to write newline characters to the file at some point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing string to a file on a new line every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-every-time)

Comment: Or better, use the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for reading and writing CSV files.

Answer (score 1):

I guess:

```
l1 = ["12345","325462"]
[sum([int(xx) for xx in list(x)]) for x in l1 ]
```

Which returns `[15, 22]`

Apply to each list, for example defining a method which also converts the sum to string, just in case:

```
def sum_digits_of_elements_in(lst):
  sums = [ sum([int(xx) for xx in list(x)]) for x in lst ]
  return [ str(x) for x in sums ]
  # return just sums to return integers
```

To be used as

```
l2 = ["214356","53645"]
sum_digits_of_elements_in(l2)
#=> ['21', '23']
```

Comment: The OP wants the results as a set of strings.  So you could additionally put a `str()` around the `sum()` function.  Then again, if everything is being written to .csv anyway, then it might not matter here.