# How to write the output of a python in a text file in separated lines?

Tags: python, text, output

I want to write the output of my phyton program in a text file. The output is in a loop and I want that each output be in one line. I am using this code for writing, but still I will give all the result in one line.

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    out = P2[16:3276,:].sum(axis=0)
    outfile.write("{}\n".format(out))
```

The actual result is:

```
[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
```

But I want to be like this:

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) instead:

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    out = P2[16:3276,:].sum(axis=0)
    outfile.write("\n".join(map(lambda x: '%f' % x, out)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-every-time

Comment: Thanks. But my output is mot string. With this code I will have this error: sequence item 0: expected str instance, numpy.float32 found

Comment: I did not down vote your answer. It will be a -1 for me, so I did not.

Comment: @Zahra Try now.

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. But for some of out put I will have scientific numbers like "3.23108e-08". Do you how can I avoid to have this and just have some float numbers?

Comment: @Zahra Try now.

Answer (score 0):

u can use replace, depend what's your output, but it can work

```
r = { "[": "", ".": "\n", "]": ""}

for x,y in r.items():
        out = out.replace(x, y)
```