# How to write ascii encoded newline character to a file with python

Tags: python, character-encoding, ascii

I thought this should work:

```py
file = open('filename.ppm', 'wb')
file.write('upper\nlower'.encode(encoding='ascii'))
```

When I run the code, though there is no linebreak; 
the `filename.pmm` contains 'upperlower' when opened with notepad.

Comment: There is nothing, it reads upperlower. I open the file with notepad after the code runs.

Comment: can you drop the encode part? This should be the right way to do it despite that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918362/writing-string-to-a-file-on-a-new-line-every-time

Comment: It gives a TypeError saying a bytes object is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the encoding in `open()`:

```
>>> with open("filename.ppm", "w", encoding="ascii") as f:
...     f.write("upper\nlower")

$ cat filename.ppm
upper
lower $
```

The documentation for the [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open) function may have several clues as to why your current method gives you something you didn't expect.

Firstly, regarding the newline and `\n` versus `\r\n`:

> When writing output to the stream, if newline is None, any '\n' characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If newline is '' or '\n', no translation takes place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any '\n' characters written are translated to the given string.

My guess is that, in your case, because you're writing *bytes* to the output stream, that translation may not occur as the 'raw' bytes are written to file.

One last thing worth mentioning is the use of `encoding="ascii"`.  In this case, that shouldn't actually matter, because *ASCII is a subset of Unicode, and all of your characters fall in the ASCII range.*

```
>>> all(i.isascii() for i in "upper\nlower")
True
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write to a file in *binary* mode (`'wb'`), Python writes *exactly* the bytes that you provide.  Thus, if you write `'foo\nbar'`, that is what gets written to disk - even if `'\n'` is not recognised as a newline marker on the platform running your code.

If you write to a file in *text* mode (`'w'`), Python will [convert](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) `'\n'` to the appropriate newline marker for the platform running the code, as long as you don't set the `newline` parameter:

> When writing output to the stream, if newline is None, any '\n' characters written are translated to the system default line separator, os.linesep. If newline is '' or '\n', no translation takes place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any '\n' characters written are translated to the given string.

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses `\r\n` to represent a new line whereas Linux just uses `\n`. Add the `\r` carriage return to see the line breaks in notepad.

```
file.write('upper\r\nlower')
```